# Windows Server 2019 IP Group for Firewall

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I have a couple of Windows Server 2016 and 2019 boxes and wish to add some simple rules to the Windows Defender Firewall (e.g. RDP Port, FTP Ports, etc.), allowing a group of IP addresses.  I'd prefer not to use Group Policy, but rather just the firewall itself.  Is there a way to create a Group of IPs (e.g. 10 ip addresses), and apply the group to multiple rules in the firewall?  That way, if any of the IP addresses change, I would only need to update the IP Group, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power shell would be your best bet.

Check out this stack overflow article.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366963/powershell-script-to-add-multiple-remote-address-to-firewall-rules/35367349

Comment: Thanks.  But crazy that MS makes you jump through all these hoops just to setup a group of IPs to allow in the firewall.